# Do AutoHotKey support Infragistics controls?

Tags: autohotkey, infragistics

I am trying to automate a windows based application, which uses several Infragistics controls. I uses *AutoIt3 Window Spy* to detect the control but it only show class ClassNN, Not the value. I tried to retrieved the value using function *ControlGetText*  and *ControlGet*    but failed.

- Is there work around for that ? or AutoHotKey does not support Infragistics controls?

Please help.

Comment: What are infragistic controls. I have tried to Google, without any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoHotKey and the Infragistics software are two separate beasts. So you can't easily combine them.